# What is the source and substance of the kabbalistic holiday on 17 Shevat?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chagim-holidays, ramchal

In the work of [Isiah Tishby](http://books.google.com/books?id=lLLXAAAAMAAJ&q=17%20shevat#search_anchor) he records a kabbalistically based holiday celebrated by the Ramchal and his followers on the 17th of Shevat. I'm looking for any further information on this holiday including its origins, what it is celebrating and how to celebrate it.

Answer (score 2):

Sefer Ohr Olam (Mechon Ramchal Yerushalayim) says that on the 17th of Shevat 5491 the Ramchal established the "Chabura Kadisha".  Unfortunately, I don't know what that is or why it was deemed so significant as to warrant a holiday to celebrate its founding.

Comment: What is the Chabura Kadisha? And why is it worth eternally celebrating its founding?

Comment: I do not know. However it is mentioned in the Sefer quoted as the reason for this celebration. Perhaps someone can enlighten the rest of us as to what this was and why the celebration?